# Написать в родительном падеже: Федерального государственного бюджетного учреждения профессиональная образовательная организация «ГУОР»?

Tags: склонение

Как написать в родительном падеже название: директор Федерального государственного бюджетного учреждения профессиональная образовательная организация «Государственное училище (техникум) олимпийского резерва»? Или директор Федерального государственного бюджетного учреждения профессиональной образовательной организации «Государственное училище (техникум) олимпийского резерва»?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что верно так:

...*директор Федерального государственного бюджетного учреждения **профессиональной образовательной организации** «Государственное училище (техникум) олимпийского резерва»*

В этом случае имя собственное делится на  две тематические группы (название по виду собственности и основное название по виду  деятельности).

Основное название, заключенное в кавычки, не склоняется.

Первая же часть состоит их двух неоднородных названий, поэтому надо склонять обе части на равных основаниях.

Comment: Sharon, интуитивно я тоже думала, что именно так правильно писать. Вы же очень подробно объяснили, почему именно так.  Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, Марина. Нам иногда задают похожие вопросы, но вот такой вариант названия (где две части не разделены знаком) раньше не встречался. Поэтому пришлось написать  "Я думаю, что верно так.